# Why can private fun shouldRandomlyFail(): Boolean = ++requestCount % 5 == 0 return different result?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

The Code A is from offical sample code [here](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/JetNews/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetnews/data/posts/impl/FakePostsRepository.kt).

1: What does `++requestCount` mean?  Normally I use `requestCount++`.

2: I comprehend that the author use the `fun shouldRandomlyFail()` to simulate a real network, the author think that it returns *True* sometimes and  it returns *False* sometimes.
But I don't think the `fun shouldRandomlyFail()` will work as the author expected, you know that `requestCount` is locale variable and never save data, so `fun shouldRandomlyFail()` will return fixed value. Am I right?

**Code A**

```
class FakePostsRepository : PostsRepository {

    override suspend fun getPosts(): Result<List<Post>> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            delay(800) // pretend we're on a slow network
            if (shouldRandomlyFail()) {
                Result.Error(IllegalStateException())
            } else {
                Result.Success(posts)
            }
        }
    }

    private var requestCount = 0

    /**
     * Randomly fail some loads to simulate a real network.
     *
     * This will fail deterministically every 5 requests
     */
    private fun shouldRandomlyFail(): Boolean = ++requestCount % 5 == 0
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`++` can be used as a pre-increment or post-increment operator (same for `--`). `++variable` is the pre-increment form, where `variable` will be incremented and then the value returned, while `variable++` is the post increment form, the effect is that the original value of `variable` is returned and then he value is incremented (this is conceptually what happens).
You can find more info here : [Increment and Decrement Operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators)

For your second question, `requestCount` is not a local variable, it is a class member, so the variable scope is to the instance of the class, which lives beyond the scope of the method call on the instance.